# KMM Project Build for iOS Without Running

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Maybe I'm just missing something but is there a way to trigger the iOS build in Android Studio for a KMM project that doesn't launch the simulator once the build is done?

When looking at the iosApp run configuration I see it has "Build iOS application" listed under "Before Launch" which makes me suspect this is possible but I didn't see it listed as a gradle task or anywhere else I could think of.

I've been doing the iOS work in Xcode and when I make changes to the shared code I want to rebuild it without running the app (which I've been doing from inside Xcode).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a solution, but I found that when you hit build in Xcode it builds the Kotlin code so any changes to the shared module are included automatically. No need to do iOS builds from Android Studio.